# Matlab: Merging all plot curves in single figure

Tags: matlab

I'm new to matlab and i have three figure with single plot curve in it. I need to merge all the curves into single figure. How do i do it?

Code:

```
figure;
plot(RedInd,hRed);
leg = legend('Red','Blue','Green')
title('Histogram Red Channel');


figure;
plot(BlueInd,hBlue);
title('Histogram Blue Channel');

figure;
plot(GreenInd,hGreen);
title('Histogram Green Channel');
```

Comment: you can write also `plot(RedInd,hRed,'r',BlueInd,hBlue,'b',GreenInd,hGreen,'g'); legend('Red','Blue','Green')`

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the "hold on" command.

e.g.,

```
plot(x);
hold on;
plot(y);
plot(z);
hold off;
```